# How do I rename entries in a specific column of a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame in R?

Tags: r, spatial, rgdal, spatial-data-frame

I have a SpatialPolygonDataFrame loaded in R. There is a specific column with entries I want to rename to correct typos.

`Data$Material` has the attributes of PIPES, PILINGS, TIRES, etc. I want to rename these to Pipes, Pilings, Tires, etc.

I have used `relabel()` `rename.vars()` `rename()` and all run without any error messages, but there is no change in the data. Below is an example of my code.

`mat<- memisc::relabel(Data$Material,"PILINGS"=="Pilings","Pipe"=="Pipes","PIPE"=="Pipes","TIRES"=="Tires")`

`Data$Material_Clean <- NA`
`Data$Material_Clean <- mat`

`Data$Material_Clean` has the exact same attributes as Data$Material with none of the renamed variables.

How do I rename the specified variables?

Comment: Have you tried using the `sf` package? Fairly easy to rename using that syntax. https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and the best solution I could find was to use `setNames` from `stats`:

```
Data <- setNames(Data, c("Pilings", "Pipes", "Tires"))
```

Unfortunately, this means you need to include all columns - not just the ones you want to rename. So if you have many columns just get their names as a vector (e.g. using `names(Data)`), change the names of the ones you want to rename, then pass the updated vector as the second arg to `setNames()`.